# how do I remove python 2.7.16

Tags: python3, debian, python-2.7

I need to remove python 2.7.16 but even If I use: `sudo apt-get purge python2.7` doing `python --version` still prints `Python 2.7.16` I need to have python 3.6+. plz help

Comment: Have you considered using a tool like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)?

Comment: What version Ubuntu are you running?  Python 2.7 might be necessary for some of them for system scripts.  Did you install, or do you already have python-3 (they may be installed and run separately, just don't change the system default or you will break things).  Make a local change like adding an alias for python to the one you want.

Comment: Ubuntu is using python for a lot of stuff. If you remove a version needed by your (un-specified) Ununtu release, you will break your system badly.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not already have a version python 3? Run the command "Which python3" or "python3 --version". To use python 2, the command is "python", whereas to use python 3, the command is python3.

Comment: We don't know your OS & release details; so can't know if `python2` is installed by default, you've installed it, or its necessary.  You've tagged debian packaging (shared between Ubuntu and Debian), so how does that apply to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to remove python 2.7.16, you could install both versions side by side.
Then you can choose which one is the default that is executed with `python` using `update-alternatives`, as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1142984/226614).
You could always run explicitly `python3` as [mentioned by ICE_Plane](https://askubuntu.com/a/1339403/226614), but it would not work with scripts, etc., which invoke `python`.

Actually, you probably wouldn't want to remove python 2.7.16, see [Is it safe to remove Python 2.7.15rc1 from Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149812/is-it-safe-to-remove-python-2-7-15rc1-from-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 1):

use `python3` and it runs with python 3

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the Debian 11 (bullseye) and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (focal) releases use

```bsh
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```